# Supermarket Queue Problem - Python (Object Oriented)

Tags: python, algorithm, object, math, queue

I have a real-world scenario problem.

It's about a cashier's queueing system. The objective is to be able to efficiently serve 30 customers at the shortest possible time. Cashier 1 takes 20s to scan an item, Cashier 2  takes 30s to scan an item, and Cashier 3 finishes scanning a shopping item after 40s.

The algorithm's approach is that a customer shops for 1-5 minutes (randomly), buys anything between 1-10 items, and then lines up to any of the 3 given cashiers that seem to have the shortest queueing time.

Create a class object queue, and using this queue, write a python code that simulates the algorithm without using the functions: enumeration and lambda, and the import time module

So far I've tried this algorithm:

```
import random

class Customer:
  def __init__(self, id, arrivalTime):
    self.id = id
    self.arrivalTime = arrivalTime
    self.items = random.randit(1,10)

class Cashier:
  def __init__(self, id, scanningTime):
    self.id = id
    self.scanningTime = scanningTime
    self.currentCust = None
    self.finish = 0

  def serveCust(self, customer, currentTime):
    self.currentCust = customer
    self.finish = currentTime + customer.items * self.scanningTime

  def is_available(self, currentTime):
    return self.finish <= currentTime

  def finish_serv(self):
    customer = self.currentCust
    self.currentCust = None
    self.finish = 0 
    return customer

class BQ:
  def __init__(self, numCashier, cashierScanTime):
    self.customers = []
    self.cashiers = []
    for i in range(numCashier):
      self.cashiers.append(Cashier(i, cashierScanTime[i]))
    self.numCustServed = 0
    self.totalWaitTime = 0

  def addCust(self, currentTime):
    customer = Customer(len(self.customers), currentTime)
    self.customers.append(customer)

  def serveCust(self, currentTime):
    for cashier in self.cashiers:
      if cashier.is_available(currentTime) and self.customers:
        minItemsCust = self.customers[0]
        for customer in self.customers:
          if customer.items < minItemsCust.items:
            minItemsCust = customer
        self.customers.remove(minItemsCust)
        self.totalWaitTime += currentTime - minItemsCust.arrivalTime
        cashier.serveCust(minItemsCust, currentTime)
        self.numCustServed += 1

  def run(self, numCust):
    currentTime = 0
    for i in range(numCust):
      self.addCust(currentTime)
      currentTime += random.randit(60,300)
    while self.customers:
      self.serveCust(currentTime)
      currentTime += 1
    averageWaitTime = self.totalWaitTime / self.numCustServed
```

I'm generally just lost as to how to make this more efficient and how to make it actually work

Comment: Please provide (non-trivial) sample input and expected output for it. Then explain what goes wrong in your attempt in relation to that input.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import random

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue1 = []
        self.queue2 = []
        self.queue3 = []
        self.time = 0

    def shortest_queue(self):
        if len(self.queue1) <= len(self.queue2) and len(self.queue1) <= len(self.queue3):
            return self.queue1
        elif len(self.queue2) <= len(self.queue1) and len(self.queue2) <= len(self.queue3):
            return self.queue2
        else:
            return self.queue3

    def add_customer(self, customer):
        shortest = self.shortest_queue()
        shortest.append(customer)

    def process_customers(self):
        while len(self.queue1) > 0 or len(self.queue2) > 0 or len(self.queue3) > 0:
            if len(self.queue1) > 0:
                self.queue1[0]["items"] -= 1
                if self.queue1[0]["items"] == 0:
                    self.queue1.pop(0)
            if len(self.queue2) > 0:
                self.queue2[0]["items"] -= 1
                if self.queue2[0]["items"] == 0:
                    self.queue2.pop(0)
            if len(self.queue3) > 0:
                self.queue3[0]["items"] -= 1
                if self.queue3[0]["items"] == 0:
                    self.queue3.pop(0)
            self.time += 1

    def run_simulation(self, num_customers):
        for i in range(num_customers):
            customer = {
                "shop_time": random.randint(1, 5),
                "items": random.randint(1, 10),
            }
            self.add_customer(customer)
            self.process_customers()
        return self.time

# Example usage:
q = Queue()
total_time = q.run_simulation(30)
print(f"Total time to serve 30 customers: {total_time} seconds")
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for helping, I'm trying to use this code with the queue class that I created but I'm having a problem with implementing it. @milke 92

Comment: `class queue:

  def __init__(self):
    self.items = []

  def enqueue(self,item):
    self.items.insert(0,item)

  def dequeue(self):
    return self.items.pop(len(self.items)-1)

  def size(self):
    return len(self.items)

  def is_empty(self):
    return len(self.items) == 0

  def peek(self):
    return self.items[len(self.items)]`

Comment: this is the queue class that i'm supposed to use, let's say `self.queue1[0]["items"] -= 1` needs to look like `self.queue1.peek -= 1` but its not working. do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).